# JpaRepository does not returns any of my custom queries

Tags: java, spring-boot, jpa

i'm working with spring boot in IntelliJ

i've extended a JpaRepository interface and created a query that is not shown in the repository variable into my controller (i've previously done it, but somethig does not works now, i do not find why)

the repository

```
package com.ITAcademy.dices.repositories;

import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;

import com.ITAcademy.dices.entities.Player;

    public Player findOneByOrderByrateSuccessAsc();
    public Player findOneByOrderByrateSuccessDesc();
    public List<Player> findAllByOrderAsc();
}
```

the controller:

```
package com.ITAcademy.dices.controllers;

import java.sql.Date;
import java.time.LocalDate;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import com.ITAcademy.dices.exceptions.PlayerNotFoundException;
import com.ITAcademy.dices.repositories.PlayerRepository;
import lombok.Data;
import org.springframework.dao.EmptyResultDataAccessException;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.DeleteMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PathVariable;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PostMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PutMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestBody;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;


import com.ITAcademy.dices.entities.Player;

import javax.persistence.Entity;

@Data
@Entity
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/dices")
public class PlayerController{

    private final JpaRepository repository;

    public PlayerController(PlayerRepository repository) {
        this.repository = repository;
        Player player = new Player();
    }

    //Get all players
    @GetMapping("/players")
    public List <Player> getAllPlayers() {
        return repository.findAll();
    }

    //Create a new player               
    @PostMapping("/player")
    public Object newPlayer(@RequestBody Player newPlayer) {
        newPlayer.setDateRegister(Date.valueOf(LocalDate.now()));
        newPlayer.setRateSuccess(-1);
        if (newPlayer.getName()=="") newPlayer.setName("Anonymous");
        return repository.save(newPlayer);
    }

    //Get a player by id
    @GetMapping("/player/{idPlayer}")
    public Player getPlayer(@PathVariable Integer idPlayer) throws Throwable {
        return (Player) repository.findById(idPlayer)
                .orElseThrow(() -> new PlayerNotFoundException(idPlayer);
    }

    //Delete a player                                
    @DeleteMapping("/player/{idPlayer}")
    public void deletePlayer(@PathVariable Integer idPlayer) {
        try {
            repository.deleteById(idPlayer);
        } catch (EmptyResultDataAccessException e) {
            throw new PlayerNotFoundException(idPlayer);
        }
    } 

    //Modify a player                    
    @PutMapping("/player/{idPlayer}")
    public Player modifyPlayer(@PathVariable Integer idPlayer, @PathVariable String playerName) throws Throwable {
        Player player = new Player();
        player = (Player) repository.findById(idPlayer)
            .orElseThrow(() -> new PlayerNotFoundException(idPlayer));
        player.setName(playerName);
        return player;
    }

    //Get success average from all players              
    @GetMapping("/players/ranking")
    public double getSuccessAverage(){
        Double success = new Double;
        List<Player> players = new ArrayList<Player>();
        players = repository.findAll();
        for(int x = 0; x < players.size(); x++){
            success = success + players.get(x).getRateSuccess();
        }
        return success/players.size();
    }

    //Get player with highest success rate
    @GetMapping("/players/ranking/winner")
    public Player getWinner() {
        return this.repository.findOneByOrderByrateSuccessAsc();
    }

    //Get player with lowest success rate
    @GetMapping("/players/ranking/loser")
    public Player getLoser() {
        return this.repository.findOneByOrderByrateSuccessDesc();
    }
}
```

the repository methods are wrote by me, because they are not shown after the repository dot.

Any sugestion?
thanks

Comment: Can you paste the whole repository? There are only imports and methods visible

Comment: Hello @Andronicus, this is the whole repository, and nothing more is needed as far as i know. thanks

Comment: You didn't even paste the whole class...

Comment: completed @Andronicus, thanks

Comment: Could be a configuration issue? any suggestion?

Answer (score 0):

I think your query method names are wrong.

I guess the last one for example should looks like this:

`public List<Player> findAllByOrderByIdAsc();`

(I guess id is your primary key field ;))

Here are some other examples: https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#reference